# Geometric interpretation of primitive element theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, intuition, extension-field

The primitive element theorem is a basic result about field extensions. I was wondering whether there are nice geometric ways to visualize it or think about it. Since field spectra are singletons, it has to be about the non-trivial automorphisms of points (I think), and I don't know how to think about it.

Comment: I was reading [these notes](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fcharles/CoursAG.pdf) by Charles and it brought to mind this question. See 1.3.15.

Comment: @Hoot thanks! I asked a separate question about that proposition [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878837/proof-and-intuition-for-a-generalization-of-primitive-element-theorem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reformulate the primitive element theorem as follows:

> Let $\mathfrak m \subset k[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$ be a maximal ideal, such that the obtained field extension is separable. For
>   general $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \in k^n$, the map $$k[T] \to k[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]/\mathfrak m, T \mapsto a_1X_1 + \dotsb + a_nX_n$$ is
>   surjective.

Geometrically, any closed point of $\mathbb A_k^n$ with separable residue field (i.e. a smooth point) can be realized as a closed point of $\mathbb A_k^1$.

---

Another geometric interpretation is the following. To be precise it is a consequence, but I am not sure whether it is equivalent.

> Let $X$ be an irreducible variety of dimension $n-1$ over a perfect
>   field $k$. Then $X$ is birationally equivalent to a hypersurface in $\mathbb A_k^n$.

Let $K(X)$ be the function field of $X$. Pick a transdence basis, i.e. a finite extension $K(X)/k(x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1})$. By the primitive element theorem we can write this extension as

$$K(X) = k(x_1, \dotsc, x_{n-1})[x_n]/(f(x_n)) = \operatorname{Frac} k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/(f(x_n))$$

, hence $X$ is birationally equivalent to the hypersurface given by $f=0$.

Answer (score 10):

Here’s a geometric argument that has nothing to do with algebraic geometry. You may find it insufficiently rigorous, but the idea is certainly sound.

Consider a separable extension $K\supset k$. One consequence of separability is that there are only finitely many intermediate fields $E$, $K\supset E\supset k$. Consider the finitely many *proper* subfields, and look at their (set-theoretic) union — not their join, not their compositum, just their union. This is a union of finitely many proper $k$-subspaces of $K$, each of them of dimension less than the dimension $n=[K:k]$ of $K$ as a $k$-space. But certainly, if $k$ is infinite, you can’t fill up an $n$-dimensional $k$-space with finitely many subspaces of lower dimension. So there has to be an element $\alpha\in K$ that isn’t in any proper subfield of $K$. Then this $\alpha$ must therefore generate $K$ as a field.

Comment: That's a wonderful argument! I wonder if this idea has been used in other contexts?

Comment: Thats a really nice argument using basic linear algebra in order to show the implication $$\text{finitely many intermediate fields} \Rightarrow \text{There exists a primitive element}.$$
But to be honest, I do not see any connection with geometry here. I wouldn't perceive basic linear algebra as geometry.

Comment: It’s geometry, @MooS because i had a picture in my mind as I wrote it up. There I was, looking at $3$-space, with a bunch of $2$-planes and lines, all intersecting at the origin. Notice that the picture was completely inaccurate, since the first *true* picture would have been in $4$-space, with a few $2$-planes intersecting in a $1$-space.  I think I could have turned the argument into *algebraic* geometry, but I don’t see my line of reasoning as relating to a.g. at all. The moral of my sermon? Not all geometry is algbraic. (But I do recognize that OP asked for an arguemtnt from a.g.)

Comment: One more sermon, @MooS, but shorter: in my opinion, anybody that teaches linear algebra without pointing out the geometric content is doing their students a serious disfavor.

Comment: I agree, that one should always have the picture of euclidean 2- or 3-space in mind, when one does linear algebra.

But one should remember: Having a picture in mind is still not the same as doing geometry. Good mathematicians *always* have a picture in mind when they think about math, even in stochastics. Would you now call stochastics geometry?

Comment: Well, I suppose that there are symbolic pictures, and soi-disant geometric pictures, both frankly merely a representation of what’s going on. I’ll say with more assurance that wrong mental pictures have been a serious stumbling block to my own understanding.