# Proof and intuition for a generalization of primitive element theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intuition, schemes, affine-schemes

A couple of weeks ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867078/geometric-interpretation-of-primitive-element-theorem) about a geometric interpretation of the primitive element theorem. A [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867078/geometric-interpretation-of-primitive-element-theorem?noredirect=1#comment3851665_1867078) pointed me to Proposition 1.3.15 of [these notes](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/%7Efcharles/CoursAG.pdf) by Charles, which reads:

> **Proposition 1.3.15.** Let $f:X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $x$ be a point of $X$ and let $s=f(x)$. Assume that $f$ is étale at $x$. Then there exist open affine neighborhoods $U=\operatorname{Spec}B$ and $V=\operatorname{Spec}A$ of $x$ and $s$ respectively, with $f(U)\subset V$, and an $S$-immersion $U\to\mathbb A_S^1$ that identifies $U$ with an open subscheme of a closed subscheme $Z\subset \mathbb A_S^1$ defined by a monic polynomial $P\in A[X]$ such that $P^\prime$ does not vanish on $U$.
>
> **Remark 1.3.16.** Conversely, it is easy to check that such a $U$ is étale over $S$. The theorem above should be considered as a generalization of the primitive element theorem for separable extensions of fields.

For proof author cites chapter V of Raynaud's *Anneaux locaux henséliens*, but I cannot read french so it doesn't help me very much.

I'd like two things:

1. A proof of this proposition (an English reference would be great);
2. An explanation of the geometric picture, and why this generalizes the classical primitive element theorem. Why is separability no longer needed?

Comment: You get the primitive element theorem from this proposition by taking $X = \operatorname{Spec} K$  and $S = \operatorname{Spec} k$ for a field extension $K/k$. Note that in this case $X \to S$ is étale iff $K/k$ is finite and separable.

Comment: This is an english reference: The proof is not explicitly given, but at least it tells you what to do. http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GU (Condition 10 of the equivalent statements)

Comment: Here is the same statement given again: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025C
I am sure if you read a little bit around these tags, you should be able to cook up a proof. This is not very deep.

Comment: how about you translate it to english? mathematical french is very simple..

Comment: I do want to say that if you're interested in this kind of stuff then reading French seems almost unavoidable (and somewhat fun/easy!). Not reading Serre, Grothendieck, Deligne... one is missing out on so much. Anyway, in this particular case it seems like the meat of the proof is [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00UE). I think he (I assume de Jong wrote this) uses the primitive element theorem; oh well. At least now it is connected to a property (being étale, as MooS says) that demands a geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. A proof of this proposition (an English reference would be great).

As stated in the comments, this is (10) in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GU, up to notational changes. You can probably find it in Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud's *Néron Models* [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-51438-8).

- S. Bosch, W. Lütkebohmert, and M. Raynaud. *Néron models.* Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete (3) [Results in Mathematics and Related Areas (3)], 21. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990. x+325 pp.

> 2. An explanation of the geometric picture, and why this generalizes the classical primitive element theorem. Why is separability no longer needed?

Let $K/k$ be a finite extension of fields. Then it is separable if and only if $\text{Spec}\,K \to \text{Spec}\,k$ is étale (this is by the differential criterion for étaleness), so taking $X = \text{Spec}\,K$, $S = \text{Spec}\,k$ we do recover the classical result (note that $U$ is the $\text{Spec}$ of $A[X]/P$ with the notations above). Geometrically, it means that $X$ can locally be defined by a single equation. Here is another interpretation: general results show that if $X \to S$ is étale, then Zariski-locally, $X$ can be cut out by $r$ equations in $\mathbb{A}^r \times S$ with the differential of these equations being independent. Now the local inversion theorem does not hold for the Zariski topology so we can not take $r = 0$. What the proposition shows is that we can at least take $r = 1$.